# .NET 4.7.2 BadImageFormat Exception random

Tags: .net-4.7.2

first of all, this is not a duplicate post. I have already searched and all the answers say the same thing about IIS targetting 32 bit or 64 bit CPU. I have tried this already but this exception is on IIS Express with Any CPU targetted.

Problem is, yesterday my MVC 5 app was working fine, I could debug normally etc... Today after i just turned on PC at office and started VS and just debug my app it just gave the badImageException ? Why does it do this out of nowhere? Also i'm using VS 2017

[image]

Comment: Try `Clean` and `Rebuild` project. Refresh all nuget packages

Comment: I tried this but didn't work, what worked for me was deleting bin and obj folders though

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets this error out of nowhere, just delete bin and obj folders, it works right after